# How did they design the Flash logo?

Tags: gimp, css

I am just interested to know how was the Flash logo shown bellow designed? How can something similar can be created using GIMP? sorry I can't afford Photoshop.

[image: Adobe Flash icon/logo]

[edit] In addition to GIMP, is it possible to do this in CSS?

Comment: For the CSS part: [Inner text shadow is tricky](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889501/inner-text-shadow-with-css). Otherwise I think it is *quite* achievable.

Comment: If you want to add a bit more wow (... I can't believe I just said that???), I'd recommend using a barely noticeable texture inside the "Fl".

Answer (score 6):

Here's my attempt at creating this using CSS. The main idea here is to use both CSS3 multiple backgrounds and gradients to create the effect - a radial transparent to semi-transparent black gradient layered over a bright pink to dark red linear gradient.

[image: Attempt at recreating Flash CS4 logo with CSS]

The glaring omission is the lack of inset text shadow, which is CSS does not, and will probably not have in the near future.

Have a look at the live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qrhSD/2/ (Mozilla only, though you can quite easily convert the rules to work for Webkit browsers too)

Comment: +1. Awesome effort.See Koiyu's comment about the shadow.

Comment: @Johannes Doesn't help, as I said it's impossible.

Answer (score 4):

Subtle radial gradient for the background. It has a constant hue. The saturation varies because they wanted a soft, plastic effect.

The "hole" effect is made via a Photoshop feature called layer styles. It's easy in Photoshop but GIMP doesn't have layer styles so I think there's no easy way there.

Since this particular logo is simple, you can just look at the basic graphic elements and duplicate them by hand in GIMP. For example:

1. About three small dark gradients for the shadows.
2. A copy of the hole-mask, shifted 1px downwards and made to additively blend with the background, producing the highlight effect before the mask is applied to make the hole

And so on.